# Asp:FileUpload and RAD ajaxmanager not working together

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, rad

I have following code for uploading a file:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlCauses" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="uplCauses" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUplCauses" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUplCauses_Click" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUplCausesStatus" Text="Upload status: " />
</asp:Panel>
```

And i have used following code to allow only pnlCauses to refresh.

```
<rad:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnUplCauses">
    <UpdatedControls>
         <rad:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlCauses" />
    </UpdatedControls>
</rad:AjaxSetting>
```

But seems Upload control and Ajax dont work together.

Can anyone suggest me alternatives ? That how can i allow only panel to refresh and not complete page ?

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET FileUpload cannot upload files using AJAX calls. You must force a postback request, or use a control like [RadAsyncUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultvb.aspx?product=asyncupload) to upload files asynchronously.

Telerik documentation has a [workaround](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/upload/ajaxsupport.html) for older Telerik ASP.NET controls on how to disable upload button AJAX calls in a RadAjaxPanel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//on upload button click temporarily disables ajax to perform upload actions
function conditionalPostback(sender, args)
{
  if(args.EventTarget == "<%= ButtonSubmit.UniqueID %>")
  {
    args.EnableAjax = false;
  }
}
</script>
<rada:radajaxpanel runat="server" id="RadAjaxPanel1" 
  clientevents-onrequeststart="conditionalPostback">
  <rad:radupload runat="server" id="RadUpload1" />
  <asp:button id="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" text="Upload" />
</rada:radajaxpanel>
```